# How can I identify what application is using a given file?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to delete some folder but this error is preventing from doing it:

> Cannot delete *[FileName]*: It is being used by another person or program.
>
> Close any programs that might be using the file and try again.

**How can I identify what application is using the file?**

I want to end the application using a *Task Manager*, but I didn't know what application is using it.

The folder is not shared and my user account is an administrator.