# How to find out which process is using an external USB drive?

Tags: usb-storage, eject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I identify what application is using the file?](https://superuser.com/questions/399659/how-can-i-identify-what-application-is-using-the-file)

Often when I try to eject my external USB hard disk, I get this message:

> **Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device**
>
> This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the
>   device, and then try again.

How do I find out what the device in currently in use *by*?

(I’ve already tried Unlocker, it always says “No locking handle found.”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) should work. just hit Ctrl+F and type in the name of the file. It should show all programs that are using that file.

Comment: type in name of what file? the question is asking about a whole USB drive.