# How do I find out what files a process is writing to?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I would like to watch a process on my system, to see what files it writes to. Is there a way of doing that?

I am on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate more than 5 years after Super User launched?

Comment: Candidates: *[How can I identify what application is using a given file?](http://superuser.com/questions/399659)* (2012) and *[Easy way to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/117902)* (2010).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicates - My brain did not allow me to think of the right things to search for. Thank you collective better brain of Super User...

Answer (score 15):

#### How do I find out what files a process is writing to?

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

It monitors file system, registry, process and thread activity in real time.

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It
>   combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon
>   and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich
>   and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will
>   make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and
>   malware hunting toolkit.

Download link http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip

Source Windows Sysinternals [Process Monitor v3.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Answer (score 1):

You can use process utilities for your usage. Where Windows itself gives several utilities to monitor the thread and I/O operations. Check *[Sysinternals Process Utilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533)* link for further details.